# Puppeteer page.evaluate querySelectorAll return empty objects

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-chrome-devtools, puppeteer, google-chrome-headless

I am trying out Puppeteer. This is a sample code that you can run on: https://try-puppeteer.appspot.com/

The problem is this code is returning an array of empty objects:

> [{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{}]

Am I making a mistake?

```
const browser = await puppeteer.launch();

const page = await browser.newPage();
await page.goto('https://reddit.com/');

let list = await page.evaluate(() => {
  return Promise.resolve(Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.title')));
});

console.log(JSON.stringify(list))

await browser.close();
```

Comment: `Promise.resolve` isn't doing anything here, in addition to the DOM nodes not being JSON serializable.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

The values returned from evaluate function should be json serializeable.
https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/issues/303#issuecomment-322919968

the solution is to extract the href values from the elements and return it.

```
 await this.page.evaluate((sel) => {
        let elements = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(sel));
        let links = elements.map(element => {
            return element.href
        })
        return links;
    }, sel);
```

Comment: The docs are unclear to me because their link to `Serializable` goes to the `JSON.stringify` definition, which clearly states objects as serializable (and they obviously are). Nevertheless, a simple `await page.evaluate(_ => { a: 1 })` will return `undefined`

Comment: Not sure if you mistyped.  But if you're trying to return that object using the shorthand notation, you need to wrap the return object; `await page.evaluate(_ => ({ a: 1 }))`.  Could definitely be the cause for getting undefined.

Comment: old comment, but @gilad905 not all objects are serializable - particularly those with circular references (e.g. parent has a property with the child, child has property pointing to the parent object). This definately applies to objects representing document elements.

Answer (score 19):

**Problem:**

The return value for [`page.evaluate()`](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pageevaluatepagefunction-args) must be [serializable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify#Description).

According to the [Puppeteer documentation](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pageevaluatepagefunction-args), it says:

> If the function passed to the `page.evaluate` returns a non-[Serializable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify#Description) value, then `page.evaluate` resolves to `undefined`. DevTools Protocol also supports transferring some additional values that are not serializable by `JSON`: `-0`, `NaN`, `Infinity`, `-Infinity`, and bigint literals.

In other words, you cannot return an element from the page DOM environment back to the Node.js environment because they are separate.

**Solution:**

You can return an [`ElementHandle`](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#class-elementhandle), which is a representation of an in-page DOM element, back to the Node.js environment.

Use [`page.$$()`](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pageselector-1) to obtain an `ElementHandle` array:

```
let list = await page.$$('.title');
```

Otherwise, if you want to to extract the [`href`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a#attr-href) values from the elements and return them, you can use [`page.$$eval()`](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pageevalselector-pagefunction-args):

```
let list = await page.$$eval('.title', a => a.href);
```

Comment: `let list = await page.$$eval('.title', a => a.href);` is incorrect. It would need to be `const list = await page.$$eval('.title', a => a.map(e => e.href));`

Answer (score 14):

I faced the similar problem and i solved it like this;

```
 await page.evaluate(() => 
       Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.title'), 
       e => e.href));
```

Comment: TIL `Array.From` takes a callback map function

Comment: Consider using `page.$$eval(".title", els => els.map(el => el.href))`. `$$eval` is provided as a convenience to avoid the commonplace pattern of having to run `documentquerySelectorAll()` as the first line of a browser function.

Answer (score 1):

Existing answers are reasonable, and identify the fundamental issue with OP's code, which is that you can't return DOM nodes from `evaluate` blocks, only serializable data. But these answers could be improved in a few respects.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60663296/6243352) is the strongest so far, because it uses `$eval` and `$$eval`, which are shorthand for the common pattern of an `evaluate` that immediately calls `querySelector`/`querySelectorAll`, but has an incorrect line at the time of writing. The correct way to use `$$eval` is the following:

```js
const textContents = await page.$$eval(
  ".title",
  els => els.map(el => el.textContent)
);
```

or, applying the same pattern to issue a series of untrusted clicks:

```js
await page.$$eval("button", els => els.forEach(el => el.click()));
```

Most of the time, `$$eval` is the best way to work with the DOM.

If you only have one node, you can use:

```js
const textContent = await page.$eval(".title", el => el.textContent);
```

If you need to trigger [trusted events](https://serpapi.com/blog/puppeteer-antipatterns/#avoiding-pageevaluate-when-trusted-events-arent-necessary) on multiple nodes, then use `page.$`, `page.$$` or on rare occasions, `page.evaluateHandle`.

For example, this pattern is a fairly common way to click a series of buttons:

```js
const btns = await page.$$("button");

for (const btn of btns) {
  await btn.click();
}
```

The same pattern can be used to retrieve text contents, but is  not recommended relative to `$$eval` because it involves many network calls rather than one, which can lead to flakiness:

```js
const titleHandles = await page.$$(".title");
const textContents = [];

for (const el of titleHandles) {
  textContents.push(await el.evaluate(el => el.textContent));
}
```

As always, don't forget to use `waitForSelector` or `waitForFunction` to make sure the elements are on the page before you query them, if they're not in the static HTML. Puppeteer also has a new auto-waiting [locator API](https://pptr.dev/guides/locators), but it's currently experimental and I haven't used it as much as the Playwright locator API. If Puppeteer's locator API gains the same level of support as Playwright's locator API, it'll probably render most other selection methods described above obsolete, as it's done in Playwright.