# Get elements from page.evaluate in Puppeteer?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, dom, puppeteer

I'm working with **Node.js** and **Puppeteer** for the first time and can't find a way to output values from `page.evaluate` to the outer scope.

My algorithm:

1. Login
2. Open URL
3. Get `ul`
4. Loop over each `li` and click on it
5. Wait for `innetHTML` to be set and add it's `src` content to an array.

How can I return data from `page.evaluate()`?

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

const CREDENTIALS = require(`./env.js`).credentials;
const SELECTORS = require(`./env.js`).selectors;
const URLS = require(`./env.js`).urls;

async function run() {
    try {
        const urls = [];
        const browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless: false});
        const page = await browser.newPage();

        await page.goto(URLS.login, {waitUntil: 'networkidle0'});
        await page.type(SELECTORS.username, CREDENTIALS.username);
        await page.type(SELECTORS.password, CREDENTIALS.password);
        await page.click(SELECTORS.submit);
        await page.waitForNavigation({waitUntil: 'networkidle0'});
        await page.goto(URLS.course, {waitUntil: 'networkidle0'});

        const nodes = await page.evaluate(selector => {
            let elements = document.querySelector(selector).childNodes;
            console.log('elements', elements);
            return Promise.resolve(elements ? elements  : null);
        }, SELECTORS.list);

        const links = await page.evaluate((urls, nodes, VIDEO) => {
            return Array.from(nodes).forEach((node) => {
                node.click();
                return Promise.resolve(urls.push(document.querySelector(VIDEO).getAttribute('src')));
            })
        }, urls, nodes, SELECTORS.video);
        const output = await links;
    } catch (err) {
        console.error('err:', err);
    }
}

run();
```

Comment: `Wait for innetHTML to be set`, where are you doing this?

Comment: `forEach` returns undefined, and you can't mutate parameters passed to `evaluate` since they're serialized and deserialized, so `.push()` won't work either. Returning `document.querySelector(selector).childNodes` also won't work, since DOM nodes aren't serializable. You probably want something like `await page.$eval(SELECTORS.video, el => el.src)` or `await page.$$eval(SELECTORS.video, els => els.map(e => e.src))`. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77597068/6243352) for a thorough treatment--the answers here are incomplete and don't show how to actually get the properties.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The function [`page.evaluate()`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pageevaluatepagefunction-args) can only return a [serializable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify#Description) value, so it is not possible to return an element or `NodeList` back from the page environment using this method.

You can use [`page.$$()`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pageselector-1) instead to obtain an [`ElementHandle`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#class-elementhandle) array:

```
const nodes = await page.$$(`${selector} > *`); // selector children
```

If the `length` of the constant `nodes` is `0`, then make sure you are waiting for the element specified by the selector to be added to the DOM with [`page.waitForSelector()`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pagewaitforselectorselector-options):

```
await page.waitForSelector(selector);
```

Answer (score 3):

```
let elementsHendles = await page.evaluateHandle(() => document.querySelectorAll('a'));
let elements = await elementsHendles.getProperties();
let elements_arr = Array.from(elements.values());
```

Comment: Can you explain what this does? Printing `elements_arr` just gives `CdpElementHandle`. How can I get data from this?

Comment: Please specify what data you want to receive?

Comment: Some HTML element properties, presumably for example, a `href` of a link (please [edit] the post to show how it resolves OP's question).

Answer (score 2):

Use [`page.evaluateHandle()`](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/main/docs/api.md#pageevaluatehandlepagefunction-args) to return a DOM node as a Puppeteer ElementHandle that you can manipulate in Node.