# access document.documentElement from puppeteer

Tags: google-chrome-devtools, puppeteer

I can get access to the entire HTML for any URL by opening dev-tools and typing:

```
document.documentElement
```

I am trying to replicate the same behavior using puppeteer, however, the snippet below returns `{}`

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer'); // v 1.1.0
const iPhone = puppeteer.devices['Pixel 2 XL'];

async function start(canonical_url) {
  const browserURL = 'http://127.0.0.1:9222';
  const browser = await puppeteer.connect({browserURL});

  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.emulate(iPhone);
  await page.goto(canonical_url, {
    waitUntil: 'networkidle2',
  });

  const data = await page.evaluate(() => document.documentElement);
  console.log(data);
}
```

returns:

```
{}
```

Any idea on what I could be doing wrong here?

Comment: As the documentation says, only serializable values can be returned e.g. document.documentElement.innerHTML.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get elements from page.evaluate in Puppeteer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53032903/get-elements-from-page-evaluate-in-puppeteer)

Comment: @wOxxOm: thx for the suggestion, the link you sent partially answers the question. I also opened a bug with puppeteer and detailed info is at https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/issues/6370