# Puppeteer: Element.hover() doesn't exist

Tags: node.js, puppeteer

I am using puppeteer to scrape some images off a site along with some other data. To change images I need to hover over a list item. I keep coming across documentation around .hover() but have had no success. However, .click() works perfectly for another part of my scrape.

```
const pptr = require('puppeteer');

async function scrapeProduct(productID) {
    const browser = await pptr.launch();
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.goto(`https://someplace.com`);
    let scrapeData = await page.evaluate(async () => {
        let productMap = [];

        //scrape other data...

        const imageItems = document.querySelectorAll('ul[class="images-view-list"] > li > div');
        for (let image of imageItems) {
            await image.hover();
            productMap.push({
                'Image Src': document.querySelector('div[class="image-view-magnifier-wrap"] > img').getAttribute('src'),
            });
        }
        return productMap;
    });
    await browser.close();
    return scrapeData;
}
```

I've seen solutions where you evaluate a page with executing the hover prior. This is inconvenient as I collect many other data points and would like to keep my solution clean in one evaluate request. Am I understanding .hover() incorrectly?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're mixing up Puppeteer functions with evaluated functions that execute in the DOM context. If you want to use Puppeteer hover, then you need to use image references from [page.$$](https://pptr.dev/#?product=Puppeteer&version=v5.2.1&show=api-pageselector-1) query:

```
let productMap = [];
const page = await browser.newPage();
await page.goto(`https://someplace.com`);
//get a collection of Puppeteer element handles
const imageItems = await page.$$('ul[class="images-view-list"] > li > div');
for (let image of imageItems) {
    //hover on each element handle
    await image.hover();
    //use elementHandle getProperty method to get the current src
    productMap.push({'Image Src': await (await image.getProperty('src')).jsonValue()});
}
```

If you need to do it in the `page.evaluate` function, you will need to mimic the hover by using normal DOM mouse events.

The reason the `click()` method appears to work is that it is available in both contexts, as a native DOM method and a Puppeteer element handle method.

Comment: Beware that `image.getProperty('src')` ruturns a promise for JSHandle. To get the src string, you need a bit longer way: `{'Image Src': await (await image.getProperty('src')).jsonValue()}`.

Comment: this was incredible informative. Thank you. I was noticing some strange behaviour in the evaluate block. When returning data from evaluate, how can I manipulate it in node.js? I return an array of product maps. But when I try to manipulate the data, i get [Object]'s everywhere,

Comment: Same type of problem. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53032903/get-elements-from-page-evaluate-in-puppeteer You're trying to pass data from the DOM context across to the Puppeteer / node context and this can only be a serializable value. So you need to return `JSON.stringify(array)` and `JSON.parse(returnValue)` to work with it.