# Using puppeteer how do you get all child nodes of a node?

Tags: node.js, google-chrome-devtools, puppeteer, headless-browser

I'm having trouble finding a way to iterate subnodes of a given node in puppeteer.  I do not know the html structure beforehand, just the id of the parent element.

```
var elemId = "myelemid";

const doc = await page._client.send('DOM.getDocument');
const node = await page._client.send('DOM.querySelector', {
    nodeId: doc.root.nodeId,
    selector: '#' + elemId
});
//node.children empty
//node['object'].children empty

//try requesting childnodes
var id = node.nodeId;   
var childNodes = await page._client.send('DOM.requestChildNodes', {
   nodeId: id
});         
//childNodes empty

//try requesting by resolveNode?
var aNode = await page._client.send('DOM.resolveNode', {
   nodeId: id
});      
//aNode.children is empty
```

Is there a way to get the children of a node if you don't know the html structure in puppeteer?

Comment: You can specify the child node(s) in your initial selector directly, either by using an XPath query (`//*[@id="myElemId"]/*[1]` ) or a CSS selector ( `#elemId *:first-child` ). How do these fail for you? Also, for `DOM.requestChildNodes`, you will need to wait for the asynchronous answers in `setChildNodes` events (see [the documentation](https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/tot/DOM/#method-requestChildNodes) on that).

Comment: Future visitors: head over to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46377955/puppeteer-page-evaluate-queryselectorall-return-empty-objects/77597068#77597068) which is a higher quality canonical for dealing with manipulating multiple nodes in Puppeteer. The answers here aren't particularly useful, at the time of writing (one is incorrect, the other is vague and doesn't offer any code).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up using page.evaluate to run some js that adds unique classnames to every element and subelement I want analyzed and then pass that back as JSON string since page.evaluate only returns a string. Then I just call DOM.querySelector on each of those unique selectors and loop through them that way.

Returning children from page.$eval doesn't give me protocol nodes that I can run more dev protocol functions on, and xpath doesn't solve my real problem because it can't recursively loop through all sub-children, then the sub-children of those children.

I'm closing the issue since labeling using unique classnames solves my problem.

Comment: Seeing your actual solution as a runnable, concrete example would be useful.

Answer (score 2):

What I would do here is to use the `evaluate` method of Puppeteer to return the children elements of your node to your script as follows:

```
const nodeChildren = await page.$eval(cssSelector, (uiElement) => {
  return uiElement.children;
});
console.log(nodeChildren); // Outputs the array of the nodes children
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't quite work. You can't return DOM nodes from `$eval`, only serializable objects. `.evaluateHandle` is possible, or `.$$`, but generally you'd want to process the nodes in the browser context and return their serializable data, like `page.$eval(selector, el => el.textContent)`. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77597068/6243352) for details.