# How to get global variable of window without async/await in puppeteer

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

I m working on puppeteer in node js version 6. Since node js version 6 doesn't support async/await I need a way to get global variables in evaluate function.

I tried the following but no luck.

```
let _browser;
let _page;
puppeteer
  .launch()
  .then(browser => (_browser = browser))
  .then(browser => (_page = browser.newPage()))
  .then(page => page.goto('https://mywebsite.com')) // not actual page
  .then(() => _page)
  .then((page) => page.evaluate(()=>{
        console.log("sdasd");// no output here
        console.log(globalvar); // its the global variable
        console.log("aaaaa"); // no output here
        return Promise.resolve("a")
    })
  )
  .then(() => _browser.close());
```

when I tried to take screenshot its was working

```
puppeteer
 .launch()
 .then(browser => (_browser = browser))
 .then(browser => (_page = browser.newPage()))
 .then(page => page.goto('https://example.com'))
 .then(() => _page)
 .then(page => page.screenshot({ path: 'example.png' }))
 .then(() => _browser.close());
```

Comment: The `then()`/`await` difference is a red herring. This is a generic ["how do I return data from `evaluate()`?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57570538/how-do-i-return-a-value-from-page-evaluate-in-puppeteer) question. Make sure `globalvar` is serializable (you [can't return DOM nodes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46377955/puppeteer-page-evaluate-queryselectorall-return-empty-objects?noredirect=1&lq=1), or the `window`, for example). Logs also run in the browser and aren't visible by default in Puppeteer, but you can add a [listener](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60075804) in Node.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you execute the `evaluate` method, it's actually executed in the **page context** ie. in your remote browser. So this is why you're not seeing any output from your `console.log` statements: they're actually being executed in the browser as opposed to being executed and output to your terminal / command line window.

For what you wish to do, you should be able to do something like this:

```
.then((page) => {
  return page.evaluate(() => {
    return globalVar;
  });
})
.then((globalVarHere) => {
  console.log(globalVarHere); // Should output the value
});
```

Comment: `.then(page => page.evaluate('globalVar')).then(console.log);` For those that find the **page context** here confusing, you might want to pass the global variable as a name `string` to make it clear it's not in the current context.