# Puppeteer returning empty object

Tags: javascript, puppeteer

When I run the following code in the page console I'm trying to scrape, I got [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OyG6P.png).

```
document.querySelector('#sb-site > div.sticky_footer > div:nth-child(9)')
```

However, when I run this in my program, the console log it and returns '{}'

```
const inputContent = await page.evaluate(() => {
return document.querySelector('#sb-site > div.sticky_footer > div:nth-child(9)'); });
```

Comment: How are you loading the page? Are you loading with `waitUntil: 'networkidle0'`? Are you trying to console a HTML element on the nodejs console or just get the text/link?

Comment: I have added that code so now it fully loads, I also added .innerHTML after the selector. I am trying to grab that giant block of text from the image in the main post so I can pull content out of it

Comment: You are trying to pull text from image? :/

Comment: tbh, it's hard to help if you don't provide more code or url, so that we can reproduce this problem. I dealt with lots of react/vue/angular site scraping, but still I needed more specific information.

Comment: No sorry, I was referring to the image I posted in my OP. I wish I could link you but it's in the admin panel and I can't share access. Here is another picture https://imgur.com/a/LaG8dU3

Comment: Instead of sending us pictures, please copy and paste just the code you want into your question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Puppeteer page.evaluate querySelectorAll return empty objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46377955/puppeteer-page-evaluate-queryselectorall-return-empty-objects)

Answer (score 11):

puppeteer can transfer two types of data between Node.js and browser context: serializable data (i.e. data that is supported by `JSON.stringify()`/`JSON.parse()`) and JavaScript object ids (including DOM elements) — JSHandle and ElementHandle. Later ones have a bit more complicated API (see JSHandle and ElementHandle methods or methods that mention them).

`page.evaluate()` can only transfer serializable data, and instead of un-serializable data, it returns `undefined` or empty objects. DOM elements are non-serializable as they contain circular references and methods.

So if you just need some text or element attributes, try to do most of the processing in the browser context and return just serializable data.

Comment: Any chance you know how one would collect an array of elements using puppeteer then and then use them later then? or is it simply not possible? For example. if I want to iterate over an array of elements and click each one, is my only option to do this from within the evaluate function?

Comment: @switch201 You can use `page.evaluateHandle()` for this. For example: https://gist.github.com/vsemozhetbyt/67c0d4951c79ee216d567a21d926bad2

Answer (score 3):

Make sure the page loads completely before scraping.

```
page.goto(url, {waitUntil: 'networkidle0'})
```

Also, according to [the docs](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pageevaluatepagefunction-args), `.evaluate` will return a `promise`, it will not return a DOM element.

It will print `{}` on console or the value the promise resolves to on console.

Comment: Note that the OP uses `await` on their call to `evaluate`, so the result will be the value the promise resolves to.

Answer (score 0):

In your case you're trying to select a custom dom object injected into the page which is leading to some strange behavior when using the `nth-child()` css selector. So you should try to target the DOM node directly instead. So let's say you were trying to get a similar element here https://wefunder.com/chattanoogafc

You can do:

```
const inputContent = await page.evaluate(async () => {
  var elements =  document.querySelectorAll("#sb-site > div.sticky_footer > div")[3].querySelectorAll("*")[0];
  return elements.getAttribute("company-json");
});

console.log("test:" + inputContent);
```

And that should return the JSON that you want. You can then parse it using `JSON.parse(inputContent)`

Comment: I added .innerHTML but now it is printing undefined

Comment: Hard to debug without seeing the element you're trying to interact with. No reason `.innerHTML` wouldn't work unless your css selector is wrong or the element hasn't fully loaded yet.

Comment: here is the original selector `#sb-site > div.sticky_footer > div:nth-child(9) > wf:loader-v2` but I had to shorten it down to the one in OP because it wasn't recognizing the ":". Is there a way to access the `wf:loader-v2` part that I think contains the info?

Comment: That's not a valid selector @RyanSoderberg

Comment: Yes, so how would I access the information in it if I can't select it?

Comment: @RyanSoderberg I got it working, I edited my answer.

Comment: Nice, please accept my answer if this worked for you.