# How can you scrape an img src with puppeteer?

Tags: javascript, html, web-scraping, puppeteer

I've trying to scrape an img src but the console keeps timing out without giving me anything.

```
async function nikeScraper(){
const browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless: false});
const page = await browser.newPage();

const images = await page.evaluate(() => {
    const getImages = document.querySelectorAll(".product-card__hero-image > picture > img")

    return getImages
})

await browser.close();

console.log(getImages)
}
```

Comment: Are you navigating to the url at all?

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55017057/puppeteer-returning-empty-object/55032557#55032557