# Document.getElementById returns "undefined", even though the element exists

Tags: javascript, node.js, parsing, dom, puppeteer

I am currently working on my project and I need to parse some information from a WebSite. I'm using Node.Js library 'puppeteer'. I need to click on the element, but Document.getElementById returns "undefined". Can you help me?

I need to click on this element:
`<div data-v-55c47311="" id="VikaWidget">`
It is located at the bottom of the page under a lot of  elements:

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
<script type="text/javascript">
<script type="text/javascript">
<script src="/widget/script.js?theme=left" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link href="https://vi.admhmao.ru/assets/vi_widget_2/css/app.4291e2e8.css" rel="stylesheet">
<div data-v-55c47311="" id="VikaWidget">
<div id="widget_main" style="display: block;">
</body>
```

It is a widget, clicking on which opens a window with a virtual assistant.
I've successfully parsed a few elements from the page, so I'm sure that there are no problems with the connection to the WebSite.
Here's my code:

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

let scrape = async () => {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless: false});
    const page = await browser.newPage();

    await page.goto('https://admhmao.ru');

    const result = await page.evaluate(() => {
        return document.getElementById('VikaWidget')
    });

    await browser.close();
    return result;
};

scrape().then((value) => {
    console.log(value); // The result is 'undefined'
});
```

Do you have any idea what the problem might be?

Comment: If document.getElementById had a basic bug as you're describing then there would be widespread issues across the web. It's far more likely that the element doesn't exist *when you try to access it*, but is added to the DOM later in the page lifecycle. I'd suggest you investigate using a load event handler to ensure your code runs when the DOM is ready, or a MutationObserver if the target element is added later following a web request/AJAX etc, or even that the page you're interrogating is badly written and has multiple elements in the DOM with the same `id`.

Comment: why 3 times `<script type="text/javascript">` without `</script>` ? that mean you need to use a script inside a script inside a script ?

Comment: That html creating the element is interpreted a script. So you probably have in the console some messages telling you that this is not valid javascript syntax. But it doesn't even try to interpret it has HTML (so are the 3 innner `<script>` btw. When you write `<script><script>`, the 1st `<script>` starts javascript syntax. The 2nd is supposed to be some javascript. So it raises an error such as `Uncaught SyntaxError: expected expression, got '<'`)

Comment: So, short answer: remove those extra `<script>`. They are not just useless. They are the reason why you have a problem.

Comment: The problem is [Puppeteer can't return DOM nodes from `evaluate` blocks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55017057/puppeteer-returning-empty-object). Use `return document.getElementById('VikaWidget').textContent`. If that doesn't work, make sure to `await page.waitForSelector("#VikeWidget")` first. If that doesn't work, share a [mcve]. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like, that you are calling the `document.getElementById` function **before** the DOM has been rendered. Try to modify the `page.goto()` call like this:

```
await page.goto('https://admhmao.ru', {waitUntil: 'domcontentloaded'});
```

When the element you are trying to get is dynamically added, you can also add this call:

```
await page.waitForSelector('#VikaWidget', {
  visible: true,
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but this won't solve the problem, unfortunately. `domcontentloaded` is actually less permissive than what OP's using, the default `load` event. See [this blog post](https://serpapi.com/blog/puppeteer-antipatterns/#never-using-domcontentloaded) for an exaplantion. OP's code also suffers from `return document.getElementById('VikaWidget')` which [won't](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55017057/) [work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46377955/puppeteer-page-evaluate-queryselectorall-return-empty-objects).

Comment: It works now! Thank you so much!