# How to get all fonts with style using puppeteer

Tags: puppeteer, google-chrome-headless

I am using puppeteer to get list of fonts that for a given webpage.

Tried the following snippet to get all fonts for a given page.

```
const selector = 'html';
const getFontProperty = async (page) => {
  const font = await page.evaluate((selector) => {
    let elements = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(selector));
    console.log(elements)
    let links = elements.map(element => {
      console.log(element)
      console.log(getComputedStyle(element).font)
    });
  }, selector);
  return font;
}
```

However, `elements` comes out as undefined.

[ref link: [puppeteer page.evaluate querySelectorAll return empty objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46377955/puppeteer-page-evaluate-queryselectorall-return-empty-objects])

Answer (score 1):

It happens because you don't actually return font definitions, but console.log them. If you don't use a short form of arrow function, you need to explicitly return a value:

```
let links = elements.map(element => {
  console.log(element)
  return getComputedStyle(element).font
});
```

Otherwise you can just write:

```
let links = elems.map(element => getComputedStyle(element).font);
```

**Update:** You also must *return* data you're seeking from `page.evaluate`:

```
const font = await page.evaluate(selector => {

    let elements = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(selector));
    let links = elems.map(element => getComputedStyle(element).font);

    return links; // <-- return data from page.evaluate

}, selector);
```

Comment: it's still returning null, can u paste the entire snippet, maybe I am messing up on the syntax.

Comment: My bad, didn't notice `page.evaluate` not returning data, see update.