# Puppeteer: Empty Children Array

Tags: node.js, puppeteer

I am attempting to perform a web scraping operation and would like to get all the children element in a `html` tree similar to this:

```
<div class="main">
    <p>Some p</p>
    <a>Some a</a>
    <br>
    <br>
    <em>
    <p>Another p</p>
    <a>Another a</a>
    <br>
    <br>
    <em>
    //...
</div>
```

I scraped the `html` using Puppeteer like so and managed to get the `children` but as a `string` format. Here are my attempts:

```
const children = await page.evaluate(el => el.children, await page.$('div.main'))
console.log(children)
//prints {"1": {}, "2": {}, "3": {} ...}
```

I then refer to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46377955/puppeteer-page-evaluate-queryselectorall-return-empty-objects) and this [post](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/issues/303#issuecomment-322919968), and attempted this:

```
 const children = await page.evaluate(() => {
    var children = [...document.querySelector('div.main').children];
    return children.map((e) => e.outerHTML);
 })
 console.log(children)
//prints all children correctly, but all as strings
```

Is there a way to get all child elements under a tag but with all the DOM attributes retained so that I can loop over each element, perform some algorithmic operation and extract some attributes.

Comment: i haven't tried it but give this a shot ` const children = await page.$$('div.main > *');`

Comment: What do you want to do with those elements?

Comment: Perform the "algorithmic operation" (specifying what this exactly is would be great) in the browser, or return element handles back to Node with `$$` and perform that "algorithmic operation" in Node, possibly using `evaluate` on each node to access its browser element to extract a property. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77597068/6243352).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Puppeteer page.evaluate querySelectorAll return empty objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46377955/puppeteer-page-evaluate-queryselectorall-return-empty-objects)