# node - save image from url using fs

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer, fs

I have created a puppeteer script to scrape some images from a website. I'm storing the images urls inside an array and I want to save each images using `fs`. How I can grab the image and it's name from the url to pass it to the `writeFileSync` function?

this is an example of the url for images `https://www.examplesite.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/cat-500x500.jpg`

```
 let images = [];
  page.on('response', (response) => {
    const url = response.url();
    if( url.startsWith('https://www.examplesite.com/wp-content/uploads/') ){
      images.push(url);
      console.log(images);
    }
  });
  page.goto('https://www.examplesite.com/shop/?product_count=150', {waitUntil: ['load', 'networkidle2']});

  page.waitForNavigation().then( () => {
    page.goto('https://www.examplesite.com/shop/page/2/?product_count=150', {waitUntil: ['load', 'networkidle2']})
    .then( () => {
      images.forEach( (img) => {
// I'm trying to save the image by passing the url to the fs.writeFileSync but without success.
        fs.writeFileSync(www, img);
      });
    });
  
  });
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to download a file with Node.js (without using third-party libraries)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11944932/how-to-download-a-file-with-node-js-without-using-third-party-libraries)

Comment: @cseitz not at all, how I can get the last part of the url that contains the filename?

Comment: You're right. I'll look into how to fetch all the images, but that link shows you how to save them. Your question is a two-parter.

Comment: Thank you for the link I didn't know that  with `http` module was possible to fetch the resource and then pass it to the `fs`. I'implementing it but I need to solve the problem of how to get the filenames from the url. At the moment I've also noticed that not all the images links are pushed into the array, also if I passy the query param to show 150 elements for each page

Comment: Perhaps [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46377955/puppeteer-page-evaluate-queryselectorall-return-empty-objects) answers the other half? You can do `querySelectorAll('img')` to get all the images and filter the ones you want to download.

Comment: I was relying on the responses since I've implemented the request interceptor of puppeteer. I think the problem is that woocommerce is loading images using lazy load but not sure of this