# Puppeteer losing context before retrieving lis

Tags: node.js, web-scraping, puppeteer, chromium

I am trying to use node/puppeteer to retrieve items from an unordered list. I am able to navigate to the page, perform a search, but when I attempt to generate an array with the lis, it breaks with the following error:

> UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Protocol error
> (Runtime.callFunctionOn): Execution context was destroyed.

Responding to the comment, here is the full code:

```
require('dotenv').config();
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
const ac = require("@antiadmin/anticaptchaofficial");

(async () => {

    ac.setAPIKey(process.env.ANTICAPTCHA_KEY);
    ac.getBalance()
        .then(balance => console.log('my balance is $'+balance))
        .catch(error => console.log('received error '+error))

    console.log('solve recaptcha first');
    let token = await ac.solveRecaptchaV2Proxyless('https://secure.meetup.com/login','6LcA8EUUAAAAAG17qfEfNaX6H8ozmI-IvmokZUnZ');
    if (!token) {
        console.log('something went wrong with captcha solving');
        return;
    } else {
        console.log('token is: ', token);
    }
    console.log ('opening browser');
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
        headless: false
    });

    console.log('creating new tab');
    const page = await browser.newPage();

    console.log('setting page size');
    await page.setViewport({width: 1368, height: 1080})

    console.log('opening target page');
    await page.goto('https://secure.thesite.com/login', {waitUntil: 'networkidle2'});

    await page.type('#email', process.env.MY_EMAIL)
    await page.type('#password', process.env.MY_PASSWORD)

    console.log('click login button');
    await page.evaluate((token) => {
        const textarea = document.querySelector("textarea#g-recaptcha-response.g-recaptcha-response")
        if (textarea) {
            textarea.innerText=token
        }
        const button = document.querySelector("#loginFormSubmit")
        button.disabled = false
        button.click()
    }, token)

    console.log('Entering keywords');
    await page.waitForSelector("input#mainKeywords.dropdown-toggle.ellipsize")
    await page.type("input#mainKeywords.dropdown-toggle.ellipsize","write")

    console.log('Click to search and filter fr groups')
    await page.evaluate(async () => {
        const searchForm = document.querySelector("#searchForm")
        searchForm.submit()
        const groupButton = document.querySelector("#simple-view-selector-group")
        await groupButton.click()
        function sleep(seconds) {
            return new Promise((resolve) => {
                setTimeout(() => resolve(true), seconds*1000)
            });
        }
        await sleep(2);
    })
    console.log('start grroups check')
    const groups = page.evaluate(async () => {
        console.log('setting grroups aray');
        const groups=[];
        console.log('about to awaait selector');
        if (await page.waitForSelector('a.groupCard--photo.loading.nametag-photo') !== null) {
            const groupList = document.querySelectorAll("a.groupCard--photo.loading.nametag-photo")
            console.log("groupis is: ", groupList);
            groupList.forEach(group => {
                groups.push(group.href);
            })
            return groups;
        } else {
            console.log('selector is null');
        }

    })
    console.log(groups);

})();
```

Answer (score 1):

Your puppeteer script is a bit overcomplicated. I am unable to reproduce an `Execution context was destroyed` scenario (of course with a different page, as I don't have a Meetup account), but the `groups` function expression is not valid code for sure, that causes most of your issues:

1. you need to `await` the [`page.evaluate`](https://pptr.dev/#?product=Puppeteer&show=api-pageevaluatepagefunction-args) method as it returns a promise, it will misbehave otherwise (e.g. logs `[object Promise]` only etc.)
2. you cannot use puppeteer API methods within the page context (inside a `page.evaluate`):

```js
if (await page.waitForSelector('a.groupCard--photo.loading.nametag-photo') !== null)
```

You rather should move this condition outside of evaluate.

3. Returning an array from `page.evaluate` is trickier than you'd expect (see [existing questions and answers on this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46377955/puppeteer-page-evaluate-queryselectorall-return-empty-objects)).

---

## Suggestion

I'd refactor this part to avoid the above issues and avoiding page context issues too. You can use [page.$$eval](https://pptr.dev/#?product=Puppeteer&show=api-pageevalselector-pagefunction-args):

```js
const groups = await page.$$eval('a.groupCard--photo.loading.nametag-photo', (groupList) => 
  groupList.map((group) => group.href)
)
```