# Scraping with puppeteer not returning any data

Tags: javascript, web-scraping, puppeteer

I'm doing some very basic scraping with puppeteer, as below:

```js
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer");

(async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.goto(
    "https://results.birmingham2022.com/#/athletic-sports-entries/SWM/*"
  );

  // Wait for it to do a bunch of background auth, api calls, etc.
  await sleep(45 * 1000);
  console.log("Finished sleeping.");

  console.log("Finding tables...");
  const eventsTables = await page.evaluate(() => {
    const tables = document.querySelectorAll(
      "app-athletics-sports-entries > div > div > div > table"
    );

    return tables.length;
  });
  console.log("Found events tables:", eventsTables);

  await browser.close();
})();

function sleep(ms) {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    console.log(`Waiting for ${ms / 1000} seconds...`);
    return setTimeout(resolve, ms);
  });
}
```

I've confirmed that the selector works fine by using DevTools. It returns an array length of 1764. The above code does too. If I change the above code to just return the `tables` variable though, it returns undefined.

- I've tried `Array.from(tables)`, still undefined.
- I've tried iterating over `tables.values()`, pushing each item into a new array and returning the new array, still undefined.

I'm completely lost as to what I've doing wrong here?

Comment: On which line in the code are you getting udefined?

Comment: @HimanshuPoddar on the `console.log("Found events tables...` line (if I do anything other than `.length` in the `evaluate` function).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your issue lies in [serialization of node elements](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/issues/2418). Your attempted solutions still try to return nodes from `evaluate`, it fails and you get `undefined`. More on the subject can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46377955/puppeteer-page-evaluate-queryselectorall-return-empty-objects).

One workaround would be to modify your second attempted solution:

```
let elements = [];
for (let el of tables.values()) { 
   elements.push(el.outerHTML) 
}
```

and return `elements` from `evaluate`. I tried this solution and you get all the node content printed out in your `console.log` but that is quite a large amount of HTML, so maybe a better approach would be to refine what you are looking for and push only that to `elements` array. Just keep the elements of an array in String format.

Comment: Ah serialization, fun times! Thank you!