# Puppeteer not showing all the elements in terminal - Node JS web scraping

Tags: node.js, web-scraping, puppeteer

I am trying to scrape the products in the below amazon URL
**https://www.amazon.in/gp/browse.html?node=4092115031&ref_=nav_em_sbc_tvelec_gaming_consoles_0_2_9_12**

I this URL the **product list** items are present in the **ul** (5 items in a row, present inside the ul)

and when I target all the **ul** in the page, its not showing me all the **ul** only few are shown in the terminal, especially the **product ul** items are not showing. Even when I target the entire body, its not showing the entire page content

I tried with waitForSelector but its not working. And if scrolling is the issue (if in case, some product ul items are not even need to scroll) it should show atleast some **product ul list** right ?

Here is the code

```
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer");

const amazonURL =
  "https://www.amazon.in/gp/browse.html?node=4092115031&ref_=nav_em_sbc_tvelec_gaming_consoles_0_2_9_12";

async function run(params) {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
  const page = await browser.newPage();

  await page.setUserAgent(
    "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/78.0.3904.108 Safari/537.3"
  );

  await page.goto(amazonURL);

  const products = await page.evaluate(() => document.querySelectorAll("ul"));
  console.log(products);

  await browser.close();
}

run();
```

the reason i wrote the line

```
const products = await page.evaluate(() => document.querySelectorAll("ul"));
```

even this general targeting is not working, once this works, I will target the nested title, price and images. But its not working.

What needs to be done ?

Comment: Please clarify "not working". Are you getting an array of empty objects? If so, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46377955/puppeteer-page-evaluate-queryselectorall-return-empty-objects) will probably get you moving again. If you're getting an empty array with zero length you might want to wait for the selector as well. Running headfully is another useful debugging technique to make sure you're not being blocked by cloudflare. What data are you actually trying to get here? The `<ul>`s on the page as a whole have a lot of excessive info you probably don't need.

Comment: @ggorlen Not working i meant getting **{ }** . using **$$eval** works correctly, can u tell me difference between evaluate and $$eval, where exactly to use them

Comment: Please see the link I shared above. You [can't return non-serializable DOM nodes from `evaluate`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46377955/puppeteer-page-evaluate-queryselectorall-return-empty-objects).

Comment: Regarding `$$eval` and `evaluate`, use `$$eval` whenever you write an `evaluate` where the first thing you do is `document.querySelectorAll`. `$$eval` is just a shortcut for that common pattern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure, why are you trying to get item by searching for `ul` tag, for me unique item card selector looks similar to `.a-section.octopus-pc-card-content .a-list-item`.

Also I saw issue, that on first load via direct link page was not loaded properly (Sign in button was shown), so it can be your issue.

Second issue can be that you don't wait for real condition properly. If you wait for `ul` selector, there can be situation when some `ul` was loaded, but your card has not exist yet.

So I added reload in the code and searched by unique item selector and it seemed to work.

```js
    const amazonURL =
      "https://www.amazon.in/gp/browse.html?node=4092115031&ref_=nav_em_sbc_tvelec_gaming_consoles_0_2_9_12";
    await page.goto(amazonURL);
    await page.reload();
    await page.waitForSelector('.a-section.octopus-pc-card-content .a-list-item');
    const itemData = await page.$$eval('.a-section.octopus-pc-card-content .a-list-item', e => e.map(el => el['innerText']))
    console.log(itemData);
```

Comment: First this solution works perfectly as expected. And as you mentioned why trying to target **ul** .

Initially this was my code


`const products = await page.evaluate(() =>
    Array.from(document.querySelectorAll("ul .octopus-pc-item"), (e) => ({
      title : e.querySelector('.a-list-item .octopus-pc-asin-title span').innerText,
      price : e.querySelector('.a-list-item .octopus-pc-asin-price span span').innerText,
      imageURL : e.querySelector('.a-list-item img').src,
    }))
  );
  console.log(products)`

But didn't work & I got [ ], so that's I tried to target ul.

Answer (score 0):

Amazon may not be serving puppeteer the same content you see in the browser. Try outputting the page content and see if the `<ul />` elements you're expecting are actually there.

```
await page.goto(amazonURL);
const content = await page.content();
console.log(content);
```

Comment: This doesn't give me the entire page content and missing product list items.  Anyway thanks for the reply