# Iterating through child elements in puppeteer returns undefined

Tags: javascript, puppeteer

I'm a beginner with puppeteer and sorry if my question sounds dumb or I missed something. But when I try iterating through the parents node children elements and trying to get its innerText (that does exist) it returns undefined?

```
let Atsiskaitymai = await page.$$("#slenkanti_dalis > table > tbody > tr")

for (atsiskaitymas1 of Atsiskaitymai) {
  let s = await atsiskaitymas1.evaluate(x => Object.values(x.children))
  for (let i of s) {
    console.log(i.innerText); 
  }
  //returns undefined
```

Tried to do:

```
i.evaluate(x => x.innertext)
i.getAttribute('innerText')
```

Comment: Please share a [mcve] including the site. You can't return DOM nodes from `evaluate` though. Try mapping in `evaluate` and returning the text contents there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple issues with the code, but the most fundamental misunderstanding is that [it's not possible to return DOM nodes from the browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46377955/puppeteer-page-evaluate-queryselectorall-return-empty-objects) because they're complex, non-serializable circular structures (i.e. calling `JSON.stringify()` on them fails).

Instead, try pulling out the serializable text content inside your `evaluate` (I'm using `$$eval` to do it all in one call and [avoid element handles](https://serpapi.com/blog/puppeteer-antipatterns/#avoiding-pageevaluate-when-trusted-events-arent-necessary) which are less reliable and awkward to work with):

```js
const sel = "#slenkanti_dalis tr";
await page.waitForSelector(sel);
const data = await page.$$eval(sel, rows =>
  rows.map(row =>
    [...row.querySelectorAll("td")].map(cell =>
      cell.textContent.trim()
    )
  )
);
console.table(data);
```

It's also good to wait for the selector, since data is often added after the page loads. You can use the new [locator API](https://pptr.dev/guides/locators) to do this, but since you may be on an older Puppeteer version, I went with the compatible approach.

If this generic table scrape doesn't work for you, please share the page so I can see what I'm doing.

As an aside, I like to avoid `>` in my CSS selectors, which is usually overly-specific and prone to fail. I'd only use `> table > tbody > tr` if I had to disambiguate a nested table, which I assume doesn't apply here.

---

JS safety tip: `for (atsiskaitymas1 of Atsiskaitymai) {` should be `for (const atsiskaitymas1 of Atsiskaitymai) {`. Always use `const` or `let` to avoid creating a global. Using [ESLint](https://eslint.org/play/) will pick this up: `'atsiskaitymas1' is not defined.  (no-undef)`.