# pupeteer button with link that executes javascript in scraped page

Tags: javascript, web-scraping, button, puppeteer, href

I am scraping a page that has a button with a link, that executes a javascript function.
When the button is clicked, a modal opens with a text area that i want to grab the content.
The button link html code is this.

```
<a id="get_code_atag_476192" href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="getCode(476192)" class="getCode"><img src="/templates/default2/images/icon-edit.png" alt="Λήψη κώδικα" title="Λήψη κώδικα"></a>
```

When the button is clicked it creates dynamically the following html with the text area i am interesting.

```
<div class="modal getCode jqmID1" id="getCodeModal" style="z-index: 30000; display: block; top: 617px;">
    <p class="title">
        <span>Λήψη κώδικα δημιουργικού</span>
        <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="close" id="getCodeModalClose"><span>close</span></a>
    </p>
    <fieldset>

        <div style="position:relative;">
        <img id="shorten_link_image" src="/templates/default2/images/ajax_loader.gif" style="display: none; position: absolute; top: 45px; left: 257px;">    
        <textarea name="copythis" id="copythis" readonly="readonly" class="">&lt;script type="text/javascript" src="//go.linkwi.se/delivery/js/crl.js"&gt;&lt;/script&gt;
&lt;script type="text/javascript"&gt;
LinkwiseCreative.show("13536-49", "CD26071", "_blank");
&lt;/script&gt;
&lt;noscript&gt;
    &lt;iframe id="lkws_653d5ccd6eccd" name="lkws_653d5ccd6eccd" src="//go.linkwi.se/delivery/ih.php?cn=13536-49&amp;amp;an=CD26071&amp;amp;target=_blank&amp;amp;" style="width:250px;height:250px" scrolling="no" frameborder="0"&gt;&lt;/iframe&gt;
&lt;/noscript&gt;</textarea>
```

Any idea on how to achieve this???
Thanks in advance.

I have tried

```
let codeButtons = await page.evaluate(() => {
        let code = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.getCode'))
        return code;        
        });
for (let i = 0; i <codeButtons.length; i++) {
            await page.click(codeButtons[i]);
            break;
        }
```

(The loop is because there are more than one button in the page.)
but it doesn't work.

Comment: Please share the page. It's incredibly difficult to guess the behavior of a page that can't be seen, since every page is different. That said, [you can't return DOM nodes from `evaluate()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46377955/puppeteer-page-evaluate-queryselectorall-return-empty-objects), and you can't pass an ElementHandle to `page.click()`. The way to click multiple things is either `for (const el of await page.$$(selector)) await el.click()` or with untrusted events, `page.$$eval(selector, els => els.forEach(el => el.click()))`.

Answer (score 0):

Found it.
await page.waitForSelector(selector);
await page.click(selector);

Thanks anyway!!